# What does it mean for a subspace to be "contained" in another?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is more for my own conceptual understanding than anything else, and is not a particular problem. It is a hypothetical scenario, which is probably not that interesting, but I am curious. So, say we have a n-subspaces. These subspaces are $U_{0}, U_{1},...,U_{n}$. What does it mean, precisely to say that some of these subspaces are contained in the other subspaces?

So maybe we something like: $$U_{0} \subseteq U_{1} \subseteq ... \subseteq U_{n}.$$ Does this mean that $U_{n}$ is the largest subspace, and that $U_{0}$ is the smallest?

Would we have to write it as: $$U_{0} \subset U_{1} \subset ... \subset U_{n}$$ to deny the possibility that $U_{0} = U_{1} = ... = U_{n}?$

I also want think of this in a more geometric sense. Say we have a couple of subspaces of $\mathbb{R^2}$: two line segments through the origin, $\ell_1$ &  $\ell_2$. If $\ell_2 \subset \ell_1$ then what can we assume?

With further inspection: it's pretty easy to visualize this with the subspace ${0}$ because every subspace contains the origin.

Comment: In the line case, they are forced to be the same, since they have the same dimension.

Comment: That's probably why I was having such a difficult time thinking of that example. I was trying to thinking of a shorter line segment, but that doesn't make sense. Would one of the subspaces have to be a plane, or of greater dimension?

Comment: Yes, in $3$-d you can have an example with a line (through the origin) contained in a plane though the origin. And in higher finite dimensions, you can have more interesting chains. In infinite dimensional vector spaces, you can have *very* complex chains.

Comment: That sounds awesome. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: You are welcome. There are some places where your kind of chain is useful.

Comment: Note that some authors use $\subset$ to mean "proper subset" (i.e., excluded the $=$ case) and some use it to mean "subset". To avoid confusion, use $\subsetneq$ which is unambiguous.

Comment: Say you have subspaces $U_{2},U_{1} \subseteq U_{0}$ what does $U_{2} + U_{0} = U_{1} + U_{0}$ mean? What if $U_2$ and $U_1$ are lines through the origin, and $U_{0}$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R^{3}}$. What does this look like? Does it work for any $U_{2}, U_{1}$?

Answer (score 2):

The concept is called **nesting**.

A definition of a nesting is:

> to fit (an object or objects) inside a larger one:

The concept is easily visualized in $\mathbb{R}$ by the collection of closed sets $U_x=[1/x,1-1/x], \;\;x\in [2,\infty)$. Then we have $U_i\subset U_j$ for $i\le j$. (Of course, the sets do not have to be closed). All the sets in a nesting share at least one common point, for example $[0,1/n), \;\;n\in \mathbb{Z}$, every set has the (unique) point $\{0\}$ in common.

The collection of sets also form a **[topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_topology)**, and these spaces satisfy the [$T_0$ separation axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space).

Your question in the comments is called a **[direct sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum)**.